# Linq to filter directories

Tags: linq

I get the followwing direcories by calling GetDirectories()

c:\app\20090331\
c:\app\20090430\
c:\app\20090531\
c:\app\20090630\
c:\app\20090731\
c:\app\20090831\

I want to the directories between 20090531 and 20090731, How can I do it by Linq?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a LINQ **.Where** statement and **String.Compare** between your min and max directory names (as strings) with x (as a string).

Don't bother using blah **.Parse**, just do string comparisions - your directory names are numerical anyways so there's no use parsing each when you can just use a straight value comparison anyways.

```
var query = directories
    .Where(x => {
        return (String.Compare(x, @"c:\app\20090531") > 0 && String.Compare(x, @"c:\app\20090731") < 0)
    });
```

Comment: Your query as written won't work, the Lambda doesn't return anything , you aren't escaping '\', and your first string isn't formatted the same. But the Compare should work

Answer (score 3):

.Where(x => x > "c:\app\20090531" && x < "c:\app\20090731").ToList()

The tolist is if you want it in a list.  Leave that off if you are fine with IEnumerable.

Comment: There are more elegant ways (parsing out the date, etc.), but this should get it done.

Answer (score 0):

I got: operator '>' cannot be applied to operands type of 'string' and 'string'

Comment: You'll want to insert your own logic there. Write a method that takes a string and returns a bool of whether the path is valid, and call that in your lambda.

Comment: Ah, too right.  Sorry about that.  I was focusing on the lambda more so than the string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = directories
    .Where(d => {
        int directoryNumber = int.Parse(d.Replace(@"c:\app\", string.Empty)
            .Replace("\\", string.Empty));
        return directoryNumber > 20090531 && directoryNumber < 20090731;
    });
```

You can also convert it to DateTime if necessary.

Edit: apparently stackoverflow, or whatever parsing it uses doesn't like my verbatim strings.